# Custom calendar where each cell will have an image and a textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a custom calendar where each cell will have an image and textview.
Is it possible to make it in a GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this library https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid.
And search for "Allow customized cell for the dates gridView" header.

Comment: answer should be more specific otherwise having only link and suggested search